# Plyer Filechooser working perfectly on Windows but does not work on Android

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

When I use Plyer filechooser on my kivy app and print the path of the file selected, it works perfectly fine on windows but when I convert it into apk and run on android, it does not work. **When I checked the logcat, I found out that 'None' was returned instead of the path**> `05-30 10:52:48.198 31664 31664 I python  : []`

When I checked the plyer/filechooser.py on github(as there is no proper docs), I came across the following statements:
Android runs `Activity` asynchronously via pausing our `PythonActivity`
and starting a new one in the foreground. This means
`AndroidFileChooser._open_file()` will always return the default value of
`AndroidFileChooser.selection` i.e. `None`.

I don't understand what that mean, but I am not able to get the path of the file. Why is it it returning None? I have enabled READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on buildozer permissions as well as on my phone.

How can I solve this issue. I want to create the app as soon as possible. Any help is greatly appreciated.

My code using filechooser:

```
from plyer import tts,filechooser
...

def file_chooser(self):
    filechooser.open_file(on_selection=self.selected)
def selected(self, filename):
    if not len(filename) == 0:
       print(filename[0])
       self.file = filename[0]
```

along with an mdraisedbutton > `on_press: app.file_chooser()`

Comment: Make sure the file paths are correct.

Comment: @ApuCoder what do you mean by that? When I am running it on windows, it prints the correct file path, for eg. C:/users/myname/thepdf.pdf, but  just returns [] on android

Comment: Normally Android storage path starts with: */storage/emulated/0*.